# Perfect CFI, TLI, SRMR and RMSEA in CFA

Tags: r, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I have a CFA result which is puzzling me and I am trying to determine why I am getting the results I am getting.

I have a dataset of 134 rows. I have a factor which I run a CFA on using `lavaan`. I have checked to make sure I have enough samples (KMO test) and there is enough collinearity (determinant). My data is not normally distributed so I bootstrapped the test. It failed to give me a result because there is no real variation in the results. When I run it without the bootstraps to trouble shoot, i get the results below:

```
mod <-  'att_scale =~ att_1 + att_3 + att_5'

fit_mod<- cfa(mod, data = mydf, meanstructure = TRUE, std.lv = TRUE)

> fitMeasures(fit_mod, c('cfi', 'tli', 'rmsea', 'srmr'))
  
  cfi   tli rmsea  srmr 
    1     1     0     0
```

The results are basically too good to be true

I checked to make sure the variance is  not negative or the r2/SMCS is not greater than 1 to confirm no Heywood Cases
I checked that the Std.all for the loadings looks ok
I checked the Std.Err and they seem to be ok and close enough to each other

```
lavaan 0.6-12 ended normally after 16 iterations

  Estimator                                         ML
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                         9

                                                  Used       Total
  Number of observations                           134         156

Model Test User Model:
                                                      
  Test statistic                                 0.000
  Degrees of freedom                                 0

Model Test Baseline Model:

  Test statistic                               130.294
  Degrees of freedom                                 3
  P-value                                        0.000

User Model versus Baseline Model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    1.000
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       1.000

Loglikelihood and Information Criteria:

  Loglikelihood user model (H0)               -625.076
  Loglikelihood unrestricted model (H1)       -625.076
                                                      
  Akaike (AIC)                                1268.152
  Bayesian (BIC)                              1294.233
  Sample-size adjusted Bayesian (BIC)         1265.764

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.000
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.000
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.000
  P-value RMSEA <= 0.05                             NA

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.000

Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                             Standard
  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model          Structured

Latent Variables:
                       Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  att_scale =~                                                      
    att_1                1.011    0.098   10.336    0.000    1.011    0.893
    att_3                1.095    0.124    8.847    0.000    1.095    0.764
    att_5                0.888    0.130    6.815    0.000    0.888    0.589

Intercepts:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .att_1            4.291    0.098   43.888    0.000    4.291    3.791
   .att_3            4.276    0.124   34.567    0.000    4.276    2.986
   .att_5            3.993    0.130   30.634    0.000    3.993    2.646
    att_agncy_scl    0.000                               0.000    0.000

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .att_1            0.260    0.129    2.015    0.044    0.260    0.203
   .att_3            0.853    0.180    4.745    0.000    0.853    0.416
   .att_5            1.487    0.206    7.230    0.000    1.487    0.653
    att_agncy_scl    1.000                               1.000    1.000

R-Square:
                   Estimate
    att_1            0.797
    att_3            0.584
    att_5            0.347

residuals(fit_adj, type = 'normalized')$cov

       att_1 att_3 att_5
att_1 0                   
att_3 0      0            
att_5 0      0      0
```

Can anyone help me to see where I am going wrong

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

Your model has 9 parameters and zero degrees of freedom, which means it has enough parameters to fit the data perfectly.

This is slightly confusing in SEM, since you might think that with 134 data points it isn't possible to obtain perfect fit with just 9 parameters. However, SEM doesn't fit the model to your raw data, it fits it to the means (3 values) and the covariance matrix (3 variances + 3 covariances = 6 values). Since you have the same number of data values as you have parameters, you get perfect fit.

This will always be the case for a standard CFA model with only 3 questions.

[This post](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/seminars/rcfa/) explains this problem very well (look out for the term "saturated model").

Comment: Thanks @Eoin. I will read the page you have provided and watch the lecture. I have also updated the code above if you think it will help. Your answer has already been very helpful for me

Comment: I think `std.lv = FALSE` might be enough here.

Comment: If you fix one of the loadings to 1, you need to free the variance of the factor. A CFA with three indicators is just identified. With 4 indicators it will have two df.

Comment: Oh, yeah, right you are @JeremyMiles. In other words with just 3 questions it CFA will always be able to fit the data perfectly.

Comment: Unless you constrain all factor loadings to 1.00 (and free the variance of the factor), or fix the variance of the factor to 1.00 and constrain all factor loadings to zero, then you'll have 2 df. But you probably don't want to do that.